# Mandrill and bounce rates

Tags: email, sftp, mandrill, email-bounces

I am using a mailing list for sending confirmation emails through Mandril, however I get a high bounce rate on most emails which means my rep is graded as poor.

Is there anything out there that can tell you what the likely hood is of the email being bounced?

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things you can do here. Here is what Mandrill recommends: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583467-High-Bounce-Rate.

It might be worth it to:

1. Make sure the format of the email is correct before sending it (example: verify for `@` character).
2. Use an email validator (here are some you can use: http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-25-email-validation-apis/).
3. Clean up your old list to make sure you don't keep sending emails to the ones that have bounced.